# Firefox add-on gmail watcher sound problem

Tags: 11.04, sound, firefox, thunderbird

I'm using a firefox extension called gmail watcher (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/gmail-watcher/)

For some reason it won't play a custom sound notification. I've got it working on a Mac and in PCLinuxOS, but for some reason Ubuntu 11.04 won't play the .wav file that the extension needs.

I tried to set up custom sound notification in thunderbird and it wouldn't work there either. Both firefox and thunderbird will play the system sound. Restricted extras are installed, sound works fine for everything except these email notifications. Any ideas? Any one else having similar issues? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Got it working by installing the vlc plugin